# SharePoint 2013 Edit Ribbon Opens when you hit return on an input form in Chrome?

Tags: 2013, ribbon, browser-compatibility, inputformtextbox

I added textbox to a SharePoint Online 2013 Page.  In Chrome when I hit enter it opens the Edit Ribbon.  It does not happen in IE.  Anybody know what this might be about?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing...

Comment: Jan 8th 2015, im still getting the same issue. My form is in sharepoint 2010, and I am attaching a click event to an input box. check that you do not have a script that is firing a post back, that is where I am looking right now